# d3.js — creating HTML table from 2 dimensional array but excluding the first inner array?

Tags: d3.js

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pingin/W7Zwg/

I have a static 2-dimensional array like this:

```
var testData = [
    ["a","a","a","a"],
    ["b","b","b","b"],
    ["c","c","c","c"],
    ["d","d","d","d"]
]
```

I want to create a table from this array but I want to exclude the first inner array ["a", "a", "a", "a"] (let's say because it contains header information). So I have the following code:

```
// first create the table rows (3 needed)

var tr = d3.select("#results").append("table").append("tbody").selectAll("tr")  
        .data(testData, function(d,i){
        if (i > 0 ) {   // don't need the first row
            return d;  
        }
        })
        .enter()
        .append("tr");


// Now create the table cells

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) {return d; })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(d) {return d;});
```

What I'm expecting to see after this is a table more or less like this:

```
b b b b
c c c c
d d d d
```

Instead what I get is:

```
a a a a
b b b b
c c c c
d d d d
```

If I change the condition in the initial data bind from:

```
if (i > 0 ) {   // don't need the first row
```

to :

```
if (i > 1 ) {   // don't need rows 1 or 2
```

Then the resulting table is:

```
a a a a   
c c c c
d d d d
```

What seems stranger still is if I change the condition to:

```
if (i === 3 ) {   // just take the last row
```

The the result is:

```
a a a a   
d d d d
```

The first row always seems to be bound to the data, independently of the key function. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")  
        .data(testData.filter(function(d,i){
        if (i > 0 ) {   // don't need the first row
            return d;  
        }}))
        .enter()
        .append("tr");
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/W7Zwg/1/)'s the demo.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that will work and maybe that's the way to do it but do you know why the way I'm trying to do it doesn't work?

Comment: @pingin the second argument to `data` is function which returns the key for that data element, not a filter function. In your case rather than that first element being filtered out, the first data element's key was undefined.

Comment: Also `testData.slice(1)` will do what you want.